# Converting files with ogr2ogr and dropping ALL attribute fields

Tags: postgis, gdal, postgresql, ogr

I want to add a gpx file to a PostgreSQL/PostGIS table using `ogr2ogr`, but my table does not have any of the fields that are attributes of the GPX file. There are previous questions here dealing with selecting *some* attributes to copy using `-select` or `-sql` rather than copying all of them, but I want to copy *no* attributes, as any attribute fields that try to go into the table will result in an error. I know this must be possible, given the option in QGIS to "Skip attribute creation" on file conversion. How do you do it in the command line? Something like:

```
ogr2ogr -update -append -f PostgreSQL PG:dbname=mydb -nln mytable filename.gpx layer -select [none? 0? null? none of these work]
```

Comment: I did figure out that it DOES work to insert the feature into the table and just skips the unrecognized attributes. But it would still be nice to know how to strip all attributes when converting a file.

Comment: From http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html `Starting with OGR 1.11, geometry fields can also be specified in the list.` I would try `-select geometry` with GDAL version 1.11 or higher. Another option is to use `-sql "select geometry from layer"`.

Answer (score 3):

I usually try to convert any files to Shapefiles via `ogr2ogr and then load it to PostgreSQL, using`ogr2ogr`or`shp2pgsql`.
A little bit complex, but i save files for history and it's easy to see changes in attributes.

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" your_shape.shp your_qpx.qpx -sql "SELECT somefieldfromgpx AS somefieldfromdatabase FROM your_qpx"
```

note that `somefieldfromgpx` and `somefieldfromdatabase` must be the same type.

And next step - loading shape to PostGIS

Answer (score 1):

In your select statement just include geometry none of the attribute fields/keys

Answer (score 0):

### Dropping all attribute fields with ogr2ogr

If the name of the geometry column in the source layer is empty, like with gpx or shapefiles, you can use a default name for the geometry column.

Using `ogrinfo`, you can find if the geometry column is empty or not. Data sources like RDBMS or Geopackage have named geometry columns. This does not apply to such data sources.

#### Using the OGR SQL dialect (default)

Using the default OGR SQL dialect, the default geometry column name is `_ogr_geometry_`. Using a sql expression with just that column is what is needed. It must be quoted, as it starts with `_`.

```
ogr2ogr -nln waypoints -overwrite -skipfailures -update PG:service=osm 2014-06-28_10-04-44.gpx -sql 'select "_ogr_geometry_" from waypoints'
```

This is documented at [OGR SQL dialect](https://gdal.org/user/ogr_sql_dialect.html#geometry-field)

#### Using the Sqlite dialect

Using the Sqlite dialect, usable with all datasources, the default geometry column name is "geometry". Using `-dialect sqlite` a sql expression with just that column is what is needed.

```
ogr2ogr -nln waypoints -overwrite -skipfailures -update PG:service=osm 2014-06-28_10-04-44.gpx -dialect sqlite -sql 'select geometry from waypoints'
```

This is documented at [OGR Sqlite dialect](https://gdal.org/user/sql_sqlite_dialect.html#geometry-field)